# phpStorm - Fill out 'Absolute path on the server' automatically - localhost server

Tags: php, apache, debugging, xampp, phpstorm

I've set up a webserver locally using XAMPP and I'm using PhpStorm together with Xdebug. In order to do proper step by step php debugging, I have to set path mappings in the phpStorm server settings.

My question is: Can I make phpStorm **automatically** fill out the 'Absolute path on the server' instead of having to type it in / pick it from the drop down menu for every file/folder in my project? Below i filled out the path for 10 items (both files and folders) as seen on the right side..

[image]

Comment: No. Why do you need to do this for every folder? Can you just assign top level folder? All subfolders will inherit it .. and if necessary you can specify another path for specific files/folders if required.

Comment: You're completely right! Thanks!

Comment: Actually.. Just by assigning the top level folder doesn't work. I still get a "Remote file path '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/index.php' is not mapped to any file path in project"...

Comment: Since I have no clue what assignments you have done there and what's your project structure -- I cannot give you any better advice. My another question is: Why do you have such folder structure that 1 folder is in one place, another in another? Wouldn't it be easier if you keep it all under one folder/one place?

Comment: BTW -- path mappings are used for remote debugging .. or local when symbolic links are used. Can you just open the project from a place where no symbolic links are in use? If you do so .. then you may not even need to do any path mapping at all (so you will have to uncheck "Use path mapping..." option).

Comment: As far as I remember `/Application/XAMPP/htdocs` is a symbolic link for `/Application/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs` (or other way around).

Comment: My suggestion is this: 1) Create a folder for your projects which does not use any symbolic links (e.g. `/Projects`) 2) Move all your project files there (so it will be like `/Projects/my-site.com`); 3) Backup and delete `.idea` subfolder (your project settings) 4) Using PhpStorm just "Open" that folder 5) In your `/Application/XAMPP/htdocs` folder (or whatever the website root is) create symlink to your new project location. This way you work with files with no path mappings required (potentially, depends on where 3rd party libs are stored) and still accessing website using the same URL.

Comment: Yep - If I add the project as /Application/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs, I don't need to do the path mappings afterall. Thanks for the pin-point!